# How to change text color on press of a particular textview in a linearlayout

Tags: android, colors, textview, selector

I have a Linear layout with 3 text views. I want to change the text view's font color when any of the text view is selected. I would like to retain the new color until another text view is selected. Basically this linear layout should mimic check box's selection behavior. I would like to use the selector to change the color of the text view's font color.

I used the below selector on text view's textColor and this only changes the font color as long as the text view is pressed

```
 android:textColor="@drawable/selector_header_text"
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/blue"></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <item android:color="@color/light_gray"></item>

</selector>
```

How can I make my text views in linear layout to retain text color as long as its selected and not just pressed ?

Comment: try to set EditText.setSelected(true );

Answer (score 8):

add the code `android:state_selected="true"` to your selector file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/blue"></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <item android:color="@color/light_gray"></item>

</selector>
```

In your class file add the following code,

```
textView.setselected(true);
```

Comment: This changes font color as desired but when I click on the other textview this font color should change to default color. Basically toggling is not happening

Comment: now add textView.setSelected property for that TextView you have selected in OnClickListener() and add textView.setSelected(false) for the previous one you have selected...

Comment: This answer is useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:state_checked`, in addition or instead of `android:state_pressed`.