# Custom style on TextView widget

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to create a custom textview style where the text color changes on focus or on being selected and when released or not focused it changes back to the default color I have set. Below is my custom style I declared and applied to the `style` element of my textview

```
 <style name="CustomTextview" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.TextView">
    <item name="android:state_pressed">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <item name="android:state_selected">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <item name="android:state_focused">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>


 <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:editable="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        style="@style/CustomTextview"
        android:focusable="true"/>
```

Currently nothing happens when I toch the textview, the default color is black and when I press the textview the color remains black.

Comment: Can you post relevant java code as well as the xml file containing your textview?

Comment: I believe you can achieve this by just setting color from listeners on the textview. Like isFocused etc etc...

Comment: [This might be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783407/how-to-change-text-color-on-press-of-a-particular-textview-in-a-linearlayout)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android selector & text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [selector resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this tutorial `http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html`

Then you need to sect text color of TextView with color that you have define